# How to align UILabel Horizontally with the profile photo image?

Tags: ios, autolayout, constraints, xcode8

I have to show the Name and EmailID aligned horizontally properly with the Profile Image . So that the Name and email ID appears exactlybat the center of the UIImageView.

[image: Side Menu with the profile name and EmailID]

But you can see the name and email id are not in centre with the profile image. Why is this happening? I have given the following constraints:

[image: ImageView]

[image: NameLabel]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove leading and trailing Constrain and set align center x to imageView.

You can also set leading and trailing Constrain. but both are equal as follow.

[image]

Comment: i will check and let you know

Answer (score 1):

Just `control+drag` from label to imageview and select Center Horizontally.

Answer (score 1):

Ctrl drag from the labels to the imageview and choose `Center horizontally`.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

I know the question has been answered but this is best solution horizontal stack view

Answer (score 1):

*Ctrl+drag* from image and labels to their superview  and select `Center Horizontally in Container`.

Answer (score 1):

Using AutoResizing Tool:

Step1: **Place your image view and labels exactly how do you needed.**

Step2: **Select Image view and click on Size Inspector.**

Step3: **Simply click on red bars of autoresizing subview to de-select it which is shown in below image.**

Step4: **Repeat same steps for labels. I made labels text alignment as centre.**

[image]